# How to execute code in Real World Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Firstly - apologies. This is the first Haskell code I'm ever compiling. I'm compiling some code straight out of Real World Haskell Chapter 24. The code uses a MapReduce engine implemented in another source file to count the number of words in a line. Here is the code:

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad (forM_)
import Data.Int (Int64)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as LB
import System.Environment (getArgs)

import LineChunks (chunkedReadWith)
import MapReduce (mapReduce, rnf)

lineCount :: [LB.ByteString] -> Int64
lineCount = mapReduce rdeepseq (LB.count '\n')
                      rdeepseq sum

main :: IO ()
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  forM_ args $ \path -> do
    numLines <- chunkedReadWith lineCount path
    putStrLn $ path ++ ": " ++ show numLines
```

This code compiles fine, and I get a LineCount.exe.

Now, how should I actually use it to count lines in a file? I have a file 'test', which contains some test text. But when I do:

```
LineCount test
```

on the command line, I get:

```
Exception: test: hGetBufSome: illegal operation (handle is closed)
```

What could be wrong?

Here is more of the code in another file:

```
module LineChunks
    (
      chunkedReadWith
    ) where

import Control.Exception (bracket, finally)
import Control.Monad (forM, liftM)
import Control.Parallel.Strategies (NFData, rdeepseq)
import Data.Int (Int64)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as LB
import GHC.Conc (numCapabilities)
import System.IO

data ChunkSpec = CS {
      chunkOffset :: !Int64
    , chunkLength :: !Int64
    } deriving (Eq, Show)

withChunks :: (NFData a) =>
              (FilePath -> IO [ChunkSpec])
           -> ([LB.ByteString] -> a)
           -> FilePath
           -> IO a
withChunks chunkFunc process path = do
  (chunks, handles) <- chunkedRead chunkFunc path
  let r = process chunks
  (rdeepseq r `seq` return r) `finally` mapM_ hClose handles

chunkedReadWith :: (NFData a) =>
                   ([LB.ByteString] -> a) -> FilePath -> IO a
chunkedReadWith func path =
    withChunks (lineChunks (numCapabilities * 4)) func path
{-- /snippet withChunks --}

{-- snippet chunkedRead --}
chunkedRead :: (FilePath -> IO [ChunkSpec])
            -> FilePath
            -> IO ([LB.ByteString], [Handle])
chunkedRead chunkFunc path = do
  chunks <- chunkFunc path
  liftM unzip . forM chunks $ \spec -> do
    h <- openFile path ReadMode
    hSeek h AbsoluteSeek (fromIntegral (chunkOffset spec))
    chunk <- LB.take (chunkLength spec) `liftM` LB.hGetContents h
    return (chunk, h)
{-- /snippet chunkedRead --}

{-- snippet lineChunks --}
lineChunks :: Int -> FilePath -> IO [ChunkSpec]
lineChunks numChunks path = do
  bracket (openFile path ReadMode) hClose $ \h -> do
    totalSize <- fromIntegral `liftM` hFileSize h
    let chunkSize = totalSize `div` fromIntegral numChunks
        findChunks offset = do
          let newOffset = offset + chunkSize
          hSeek h AbsoluteSeek (fromIntegral newOffset)
          let findNewline off = do
                eof <- hIsEOF h
                if eof
                  then return [CS offset (totalSize - offset)]
                  else do
                    bytes <- LB.hGet h 4096
                    case LB.elemIndex '\n' bytes of
                      Just n -> do
                        chunks@(c:_) <- findChunks (off + n + 1)
                        let coff = chunkOffset c
                        return (CS offset (coff - offset):chunks)
                      Nothing -> findNewline (off + LB.length bytes)
          findNewline newOffset
    findChunks 0
{-- /snippet lineChunks --}

-- Ensure that a series of ChunkSpecs is contiguous and
-- non-overlapping.
prop_contig (CS o l:cs@(CS o' _:_)) | o + l == o' = prop_contig cs
                                    | otherwise = False
prop_contig _ = True
```

Comment: Sounds like lazy `IO` rearing its ugly head.

Comment: You aren't going to get much helpful advice without providing `chunkedReadWith`, maybe more.

Comment: Editing the question to provide it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to "ch24" directory in the Real World Haskell accompanying code, make the following changes and run

ghc -O2 --make -threaded LineCount && ./LineCount LineCount.hs

Then it should give the output

```
LineCount.hs: 22
```

Here are the necessary changes:

```
diff --git a/ch24/LineChunks.hs b/ch24/LineChunks.hs
index 0e82805..bda104d 100644
--- a/ch24/LineChunks.hs
+++ b/ch24/LineChunks.hs
@@ -6,7 +6,7 @@ module LineChunks

 import Control.Exception (bracket, finally)
 import Control.Monad (forM, liftM)
-import Control.Parallel.Strategies (NFData, rnf)
+import Control.DeepSeq(NFData,rnf)
 import Data.Int (Int64)
 import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as LB
 import GHC.Conc (numCapabilities)
diff --git a/ch24/LineCount.hs b/ch24/LineCount.hs
index c6dd40b..46218e3 100644
--- a/ch24/LineCount.hs
+++ b/ch24/LineCount.hs
@@ -7,11 +7,11 @@ import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as LB
 import System.Environment (getArgs)

 import LineChunks (chunkedReadWith)
-import MapReduce (mapReduce, rnf)
+import MapReduce (mapReduce, rdeepseq)

 lineCount :: [LB.ByteString] -> Int64
-lineCount = mapReduce rnf (LB.count '\n')
-                      rnf sum
+lineCount = mapReduce rdeepseq (LB.count '\n')
+                      rdeepseq sum

 main :: IO ()
 main = do
diff --git a/ch24/MapReduce.hs b/ch24/MapReduce.hs
index d0ff90b..87c79aa 100644
--- a/ch24/MapReduce.hs
+++ b/ch24/MapReduce.hs
@@ -3,7 +3,7 @@ module MapReduce
       mapReduce
     , simpleMapReduce
     -- exported for convenience
-    , rnf
+    , rdeepseq
     , rwhnf
     ) where
```

Please see the previous version of this answer for the reason of the error you got.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
LineCount < test
```

use

```
LineCount test
```

Explanation:  The call to getArgs in main takes the args from the command line.  Using "<" would mean reading from stdin.

Comment: Sorry, I was doing 'LineCount test' to start with. Edited the post to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad (forM_)
import Data.Int (Int64)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as LB
import System.Environment (getArgs)

import LineChunks (chunkedReadWith)
import Control.Parallel.Strategies(rdeepseq)
import MapReduce (mapReduce)

lineCount :: [LB.ByteString] -> Int64
lineCount = mapReduce rdeepseq (LB.count '\n')
                      rdeepseq sum

lineCountFile :: FilePath -> IO Int64
lineCountFile path =   chunkedReadWith lineCount path
```

I changed `rnf` to `rdeepseq` because `rnf` seems not to be in the "parallel package anymore.

Here's the book's companion code:
http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596514983/rwh-examples2.zip

Comment: lol sorry I've just noticed you solved your problem in the previous question.. please forget this.

Comment: Actually I didn't. Sorry about the confusion - I actually provided the wrong code here. What I mean is - I still have this problem (the 'handle is closed' issue AFTER changing rnf to rdeepseq. That is, the previous question came before this one, not after. Edited the code to reflect this.

Comment: No, you should not have changed `rnf`  to `rdeepseq` in the function `withChunks`. That can change the order of IO. The confusion arises because `rnf` and `rdeepdeq` have different types and different purposes. Try looking up the definition of `rnf` at Hoogle.

Comment: Just add `import Control.DeepSeq(rnf)` to your (buggy) LineChunks.hs and  replace  `rdeepseq` in `withChunks` with `rnf`.